# c++ programmatically efficient method to store an index that holds depth information

Tags: c++, xml, indexing, depth, flatten

I have an XML file and a library (to which I have no access) that reads the contents. This library unfortunately returns a "flattened" version of the contents of the XML file, thus obliterating the "depth" information that the XML file contains.

for example this xml file has the following "entries".

```
<msg>
    <type 0>
    <struct nelem=2>
        <type 1>
        <type 2>
    </struct>
    <type 3>
    <struct nelem=3>
        <type 4>
        <struct nelem=1>
            <type 5>
        </struct>
        <type 6>
    </struct>
</msg>
```

will be returned,through a `Entry getNextElement()` method, as

```
type 0, 
struct(elem_num=2), 
type 1, 
type 2, 
type 3,
struct(elem_num=3),
type 4,
struct(elem_num=1),
type 5,
type 6,
```

which I save in an `std::vector<entries>`.

So I have the necessary info to reconstruct the XML structure. The question is what is more appropriate and how attach the indexing info to the "entry" structure.

I was thinking of attaching an index (groupID) that contains the depth info like so:

```
<msg>                         
    <type 0>                    1
    <struct nelem=2>            2
        <type 1>                2.1
        <type 2>                2.2
    </struct>
    <type 3>                    3
    <struct nelem=3>            4
        <type 4>                4.1
        <struct nelem=1>        4.2
            <type 5>            4.2.1
        </struct>
        <type 6>                4.3
    </struct>
</msg>
```

I also want to implement a requesting mechanism to ask for a specific group of these entries. If I ask for "2", I should get "2.1" and 2.2" returned. Likewise when I ask for "4.2" I should get "4.2.1" returned. 
More or less the method should have the following declaration

```
vector<entries> getGroupOfEntries(const groupID);
```

I am not sure how to implement groupID in order to be able to use in the end an `std::map<groupID, entry*>`. Is there a way to do that when the depth is variable? Is there a completely different approach that I am unaware of ?

thank you for your help

Comment: @immibis how can it be an int if the groupID is of the form a.b.c.d .... ?

Comment: I didn't say `int`, I said `vector<int>`.